# subprocess call/popen don't work while os.system does

Tags: python

Out of 3 following lines only the last one works:

```
subprocess.call(['rm', '-f', 'temp/*'])
subprocess.Popen(['rm', '-f', 'temp/*'])
os.system("rm -f temp/*")
```

There should be a natural explanation for this phenomenon.

Comment: Alright, so what happens when you call `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.Popen`? Any exceptions?

Comment: Nothing, just nothing. No output at all as if was successfully done, but contents of "temp" remain intact.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include that information. Can you try capturing the return code for the `subprocess.call` call?

Comment: subprocess does not do globbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` calls the command via `bash`, which expands pattern like `temp/*` to a list of all files. `subprocess.call` gives the string `temp/*` directly to `rm` which tries to remove a file named `temp/*`, which does not exist.

If you like to have the same behaviour, you have to expand the files ourself:

```
filenames = glob.glob('temp/*')
subprocess.call(['rm', '-f'] + filenames)
```

Comment: Wow, incredible. Thanks. I 'll better just stick to good old os.system in such cases.